# Why there are examples of modal verbs + past/past participle on Ngram?

Tags: modal-verbs

We should only use bare infinitives after modal verbs. But why some examples of modal verbs + past/past participle appear on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20must%20gone%2CI%20must%20gone.%2CI%20should%20went%2CI%20might%20done%2CI%20can%20did&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)? Are they mistakes that Ngram captures? It seems to be an upward trend in using "I must gone." in the recent years!! Or maybe there is a grammar that I don't know.

[image]

Comment: Did you know that you can use the links at the bottom to look at the actual context?

Comment: Thanks I hadn't realized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the links at the bottom to see the context.  They are either scanning failures, editing failures by the author, or examples like this:

> Nash growled, and fought the urge to tear the fabric from her body. “I need...I must...gone.” He was momentarily incapable of forming sentences.

That is the author is deliberately forming broken speech to indicate something about the character (here it shows that Nash was under great stress)

Or, since ngrams isn't sentence aware:

> “That is US Marshal Collins, and I will be happy to tell you what **I can.” “Did** you have your badge on your belt when you went to the door?”

The sequence of words occurs but they are not grammatically linked.